# ExecutorService how to know is runnable is finished or not? Or wait until it will be finished?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

## Precondition :

I implement chating in my application and try to implement schedule mechanism. Where user doesn't have internet connection it will be put into scheduled queue.

## Problem explanation :

I have a single thread executor

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

And have a Scheduler for my Tasks

```
public class MessageScheduler {

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MessageTask> queue;

    public MessageScheduler() {
        queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    }

    public void schedule(MessageTask messageTask) {
        queue.add(messageTask);
    }

    public ArrayList<MessageTask> getScheduled() {
        return new ArrayList<>(queue);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }

    public MessageTask pop() {
        return queue.peek();
    }

    public void removeHead() {
        queue.poll();
    }
}
```

MessageTask have complete listener :

```
public interface OnMessageCompleteListener {

    public void onMessageSendingComplete(MessageTask task);

    public void onMessageSendingError(MessageTask task);
}
```

In MessageTask i notify listener about task i complete :

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // Async call
    listener.onMessageSendingComplete(thisInstance);
}
```

The my problem is when i notify a listeners by `onMessageSendingComplete()` i need to execute scheduled messageTasks in same method :

```
@Override
public void onMessageSendingComplete(MessageTask task) {
    scheduler.removeHead();
    if(!scheduler.isEmpty()){
        MessageTask readyToExecute = scheduler.pop();
        // MessageTask may be not finished already.
        // and executor was always will be busy or not?
        execute(readyToExecute);
    }
}
```

execute method :

```
public void execute(MessageTask messageTask) {
    if (!executorIsBusy && isNetworkAvailable) {
        messageTask.setOnCompleteListener(this);
        executor.execute(messageTask);
        executorIsBusy = true;
    } else {
        scheduler.schedule(messageTask);
    }
}
```

Where i need set `executorIsBusy` to **false** that `ExecutorService` will be ready to execute?

## Resolved.

After some thinking i find a solution.

I change

```
@Override
public void onMessageSendingComplete(MessageTask task) {
    scheduler.removeHead();
    if(!scheduler.isEmpty()){
        MessageTask readyToExecute = scheduler.pop();
        // MessageTask may be not finished already.
        // and executor was always will be busy or not?
        execute(readyToExecute);
    }
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onMessageSendingComplete(MessageTask task) {
    scheduler.removeHead();
    if(!scheduler.isEmpty()){
        MessageTask readyToExecute = scheduler.pop();
        readyToExecute.setOnCompleteListener(this);
        executor.execute(readyToExecute);
    } else {
        executorIsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you let the ExecutorService consume directly from the queue? It waits until an element is available in the queue, and if so executes it.

Comment: @Michael i need cancel some tasks and remove it from queue in future. Is it `ExecutorService` can do that?

Comment: Have you tried using countdownlatch, it will tell you when all your threads are finished.

Comment: @amitmahajan in this case i can't image how it helps. But anyway, thank you for your response. I already resolved problem.

Comment: @ssh, cancelling tasks is supported in the Executor Framework via Future's

Comment: @Ruslan thank you for helpful information. I will read about that.

Comment: queue is used between executor and listener, we can use wait and notify methods to handle instead of flag righ?